# Difference between Waiting and Receiving in Chrome Network Tools and Intl speeds reasons

Tags: performance, http, networking, google-chrome-devtools

Ok so I have a site hosted locally in my country South Africa, there appears to be a speed issue on the application side which is bearable, however once users access it via intl borders the speeds slow done to an even getter degree, also the receiving http speeds seem to go through the roof between x3-x5 more when compared locally.

I need to determine whether the issue is connection based or application based also if enabling gzip on the IIS instance would make much of a dent in the speeds.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network#resource_network_timing):

- 'waiting' indicates time spent on 'waiting for the initial response'
- 'receiving' indicates time spent on 'receiving the response data'

Enabling gzip compression can reduce 'receiving' time, but it makes sense only if content isn't already compressed (and I don't know what your 1.4 MB file from the screenshots is). Compressing JPEGs or videos will probably hurt the performance (since gzip compression is a CPU intensive task and there will be little, or no, decrease in the file size), but compressing CSS/JS is always a good idea.

Long 'waiting' time may be caused by slow connection or/and slow response from the server. Possible solution for the first issue is to use [CDNs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network). Second issue requires more investigation in the back-end (slow DB response time? huge server load? a lot of computations in the back-end app?).

If you are looking for more performance tips I suggest reading ["High Performance Web Sites"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529307.do).

Comment: Long 'waiting' time is a connection issue, not true.

Comment: @Chen connection, server or server application issue - anything else? I'll update the answer.

Comment: It could cause by ORM, or improper ORM implementation, assume, if there is one and there is client side call for data